# Applying Pivot in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pivot, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm using pentaho kettle 5.2.0 version. I'm trying to do pivots on my source data,here it is the structure of my source

```
Billingid   sku_id    qty
  1           0        1
  1           0        12
  1           0        6
  1           0        1
  1           0        2
  1           57       2
  1          1430      1
  1          2730      1
  2          3883      2
  2          1456      1
  2          571       9
  2          9801      5
  2          1010      1
```

And this is what I'm Expecting

```
billingid   0   57  1430  2730  3883  1456  571  9801  1010
   1                *******sum of qty******
   2
```

[image: this is the steps which I did in row denormaliser, but unable to get expected output]

Any help would be much appreciated ..THANKS in advance

Comment: Are you just trying to count qty pr. billingid?

Comment: No @bolav ,  I 'm trying sum the qty against billingid vs sku_id. I want the sum of qty against column billingid and sku_id

Comment: Can you do with a format where you get a row where the billingid and sku_id combination is unique, and you get billingid, sku_id, sum_qty, or do you have to denormalize? (The first alternative is much easier to make)

Comment: Although your first suggestion is easier but still if I want to go with denormaliser then how do I proceed with? What could be the necessary changes do I need to make in the screenshot of the denormaliser step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `denormaliser` to work, you first have to Sort, and the Group the rows, to have the `sum of qty`. So the transformation is going to look something like this:

[image: screenshot of transformation]

Sort on `billingid` and `sku_id`, and then `sum` the `qty`, group by `billingid` and `sku_id`:

[image: screenshot of group by]

Then in denomaliser you need to list each different `sku_id`, to make a column pr id.:

[image: screenshot of denomaliser]

This will give the expected output:

[image: screenshot of expected output]

Comment: that's awsome!!! it really made my day :) Thanks alot . the only thing I'm worried about now is if the number of record increase in the "sku_id" column then it would be very tedious task to manually write all values in Key value column of denormaliser step. any suggestion on this?

Comment: @Deepesh: You can use [ETL Metadata Injection](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection).

Comment: I'll surely try that step. Once again thanks :) @bolav