# Pivots using ETL Metadata Injection

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, pentaho, kettle, pdi

It's quite simple to use row denormaliser to achieve pivots when we have few records which can be written manually in denorm step,but what when there's hundreds of thousands of records? I tried using etl metadata injection step, but I was unable to achieve my desired output.

[Here is the link to my previous post where my source data has been defined.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646893/applying-pivot-in-pentaho-kettle/35692322?noredirect=1#comment59098229_35692322)

and here is what I have tried
[image]

row denormaliser options
[image]

pivot_inject_etl_metadata.ktr
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

**`pivot_inject_etl_metadata.ktr`**:

[image: Screenshot of etl_metadata]

`Group by`: `sku_id`

`Add constants`:

[image: Screenshot of Add constants]

`ETL Metadata Injection`:

[image: Screenshot of ETL Metadata Injection]

Comment: well appreciated for your assist!! Thanks once again.